# How to fix the error: The transaction log for database is full due to 'log_backup', even that shink the log also get this error

Tags: ssms

How to fix the error: The transaction log for database is full due to 'log_backup', even that shink the log and set unlimited space for maxsize also get similar error.

Solution have tried:
https://blog.hostripples.com/the-transaction-log-for-database-is-full/

What solution can used solve it even that move this log_backup or others ways

Comment: your database is in recovery model `FULL` - you have to backup the transaction log

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: should backup the transaction log first and then shink the log?

Comment: You should be doing *regular* log backups, @HoChunAng , in you're in full recovery mode.